# Can't select from a text field without focusing the text field first

Tags: bug, search, user-interface

I can't select text in the search bar without focusing the search bar first.

This problem also seem to be applicable to other text fields and text areas in the site.

[image: Can't select text in text field]

Browser: `Firefox 66.0.5 (64-bit)`

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

Comment: Seems like a browser bug. Doesn't happen for me with Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson This happened in `Firefox` only. OS: Ubuntu

Comment: Repro'd in Waterfox + Windows 7 (even in safe mode). Works as expected on other sites such as DuckDuckGo and Wikipedia...

Comment: @RobertLongson This does not seem to be the behavior with normal text field or textarea in Firefox. Selection works without first clicking on the tetfield/textarea.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Weird focus/selection behavior in Firefox on input and text areas when editing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371965/4642212). This has been reported a long time ago; this bug exists since the redesign of the text fields with the blue borders. Related: [Problems pasting into answer and comment fields](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312914/289905).

Comment: Still reproducible on Firefox Nightly 68.0a1, Arch Linux with Gnome 3.32.2.

Comment: Same issue here with Windows 10 and Firefox 66.0.5.,

Comment: @AdamLear Glad this is [tag:status-review] now! Please don’t forget to consider the [related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312914/289905) and the [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371965/4642212) when trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: @AdamLear This appears to be fixed in Firefox Nightly 88.0a1.

Comment: Seem to be working fine (can select the text, without needing to focus the field first) in Firefox 86 (Ubuntu)